# EOS: How to get structured data within transaction？Is there restful API for this/

Tags: transactions, eosjs, rpc, blocks

Suppose A sent a transaction to SC(smart contract), including structured data, for example:

```
{"intention":"like","target":"ae16xx0...."}
```

As usual, this transaction will be stored on all nodes in the network. Then, for some node X, how to get and deserialize this `{"intention":"like","target":"ae16xx0...."}`，and make use of the data？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is. You can get this data from nodes that are running with the `history_plugin` plugin. You could use the HTTP API directly as in `/v1/history/get_transaction`, or you could use `cleos`:

`cleos --url https://api1.eosdublin.io get transaction <Transaction ID>`

You could also use `eosjs`:

```
const eosjs = require("eosjs")
const eos = eosjs({
  httpEndpoint: 'https://api1.eosdublin.io',
  chainId: 'aca376f206b8fc25a6ed44dbdc66547c36c6c33e3a119ffbeaef943642f0e906'
})

async function main() {
  const transaction = await eos.getTransaction('<Transaction ID>')
  console.log(transaction)
}

main().catch(error => {
  console.error(error)
  process.exit(1)
})
```

You then just need to inspect the data that is returned and you will find the actions executed in the transaction and their respective parameter data.

Comment: Thanks for the fantastic answer! It's precise and detailed.